# showing confirmation alert message when tinymce while moving more page to another page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have few web user controls in that i am using tinymce extender editor.. and i am calling all the control in one aspx file on different different btn click.

I want, when i am edit mode and i am changing some text in that editor and without saving it if am leave that page its must ask and show the confirmation alert msg do you want to save this text.

how to do it.

on ascx file

Diagnosis:

```
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txbDiag" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <acr3s:tinymceextender runat="server" ID="TinyMceExtender4" TargetControlID="txbDiag" Theme="Full">
                    </acr3s:tinymceextender>                        
                </td>
```

extender which i am calling is

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;

[assembly: WebResource(NewCaseWizardBAL.TinyMceExtender.SupportScript, "text/javascript")]

namespace NewCaseWizardBAL
{
    [TargetControlType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public class TinyMceExtender : ExtenderControl
    {

```
    internal const string SupportScript = "NewCaseWizardBAL.TinyMceSupport.js";

    private TinyMceTheme _theme = TinyMceTheme.Limited;

    private string GetTheme()
    {
        switch (Theme)
        {
            case TinyMceTheme.Limited:
                return "limited";
            case TinyMceTheme.Full:
                return "special";
            case TinyMceTheme.FullWithImage:
                return "specialWithImage";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
    [DefaultValue(TinyMceTheme.Limited)]
    public TinyMceTheme Theme
    {
        get { return _theme; }
        set { _theme = value; }
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors(Control targetControl)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ScriptReference> GetScriptReferences()
    {
        return null;
    }


    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        Control targetControl = FindControl(TargetControlID);            
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, typeof(TinyMceExtender), "include_tiny_mce", ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"));
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Page, typeof(TinyMceExtender), SupportScript);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(TinyMceExtender), "init" + targetControl.ClientID, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "initTinyMCE ('{0}', '{1}');", targetControl.ClientID, GetTheme()), true);

    }

}

public enum TinyMceTheme
{
    Limited,
    Full,
    FullWithImage
}
```

}

i can't write any onclient event because i am calling masking script onclient click

so how to do it with the help of any jquery or java script

i am using autosave plugin also but its not showing any alert msg

do i need to change something in tiny_mce.js

please help me to show confirmation alert box to ask "Do you want to save you changes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a client-side `window.confirm()` call or an `OnClientClick` function, like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:return 
window.confirm('Are you sure about to submit the test?');" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And then in the code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");
}
```

**Edit:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function finalFunction ()
  {
    return window.confirm('Are you sure about to submit the test?');
  }
</script>
```

And then call the function that contains both scripts:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:finalFunction();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: how could i call two script on one onclientclick

Comment: i am calling that script like this OnClientClick="$.loading({mask: true, effect: 'ellipsis update'});"

Comment: do i need to call this FinalFuncation() in every web user control or only on aspx file where i am calling all the control

Comment: its showing the alert box but if am clicking on OK or Save it is redirecting to next page what i want is if i click on cancel then it should not redirect or other page and if i click on Ok then only it redirect to other page.. how to do this

Comment: if i don't want to show alert msg in btn click A in some page and in some other page on same btn click A i want to show that alert box.. is it possible if yes then how

Comment: there is only one user control in which i don't want to show alert box

Comment: i didn't get u will you please give some more description please[

Comment: there are 5 btns in my aspx page where i am calling your function.. so for every btn shall i add the attributes